# how to validate tab based list forms and save using php ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have tab panel list of forms. i am going to use jquery validate plugin and i have to save according to tab wise. how to use jquery validate plugin and php ajax to save it in database. Please check with the screenshot[image]

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#signupForm").validate({
        rules: {
            old_password: "required",
        },
        messages: {
            old_password: "Please enter your firstname",
        }

    })
</script>

   <form name="validation-form" id="validation-form">
   <input type="password" name="old_password1" id="old_password" autofocus>
</form>
```

Comment: <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#signupForm").validate({
 rules: {
  old_password : "required",
 },
 messages: {
  old_password: "Please enter your firstname",
 }
 
})
</script>

Comment: could you show me some expale

Comment: Have you prepared a PHP script to handle the incoming data? You will need a post request to pass the form data to server side .

Comment: the above code is not working

Comment: Please state the error ( try to look in Developer Console )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you an answer using jQuery. And to give you also an idea how to do it.

First is, lets get the existing password your user currently have. Then store it in a hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" id="current_pass" value="<?php echo $currentpassword; ?>">
```

Then your form with the three input fields, with assigned `id` each:

```
<form name="validation-form" id="validation-form">
  <input type="hidden" id="current_pass" value="password!1234">
  <input type="password" name="old_password1" id="old_password1" placeholder="Old Password" autofocus required>
  <input type="password" name="new_password1" id="new_password" placeholder="New Password" required>
  <input type="password" name="new_password2" id="new_password2" placeholder="Confirm New Password" required>
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Then lets create the script. I've put explanations inside using comments:

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> <!-- REPLACE NECESSARY JS FILE -->
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").click(function(){ /* WHEN THE FORM IS SUBMITTED OR WHEN THE SUBMIT BUTTON IS CLICKED */
      var current = $("#current_pass").val(); /* CURRENT PASSWORD */
      var oldpass = $("#old_password1").val(); /* OLD PASSWORD KEY IN */
      var newpass = $("#new_password").val(); /* NEW PASSWORD KEY IN */
      var newpass2 = $("#new_password2").val(); /* NEW PASSWORD CONFIRMED KEY IN */
      if(newpass == newpass2 && oldpass == current){ /* IF THE NEW PASSWORD IS THE SAME WITH THE CONFIRMED PASSWORD AND WHEN THE CURRENT PASSWORD MATCHES THE KEY-IN OLD PASSWORD */
        $.ajax({ /* START AJAX */
          type: "POST", /* METHOD TO PASS THE DATA */
          url: "changepassword.php", /* THE DIRECTORY/FILE WHERE THE DATA WILL BE PASSED ON */
          data: { "newpassword": newpass } /* THE DATA WE WILL BE PASSING */
        }); /* END OF AJAX */
      } /* END OF CHECKING INPUTS */
    });

  });

</script>
```

You'll notice in the script that we pass the data to `changepassword.php` file. You have to create your update query in this file or change the directory depending on your preference.

Example `changepassword.php` file:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("UPDATE table SET password = ? WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("si", $_POST["newpassword"], $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

You can check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Logan_Wayne/ab0vfLgt/), but without the ajax script.

And I hope that you are storing your password to your database in a secure manner. Like using [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).